# Django Formset Override As Table To Show As Grid

Tags: django, grid, overriding, formset

I'm using a formset to collect multiple forms worth of data on one page but something I realized is that the .as_table display for a formset is slightly suboptimal for what I'm trying to do, rather than print each form element as a new table row I was thinking of printing each form itself as an individual row and having a table header with the field names since I know my formset would have the same fields for each form instance. In this way you get a grid of data that a use can fill in. I've done it manually through the template where the form is printed but I was wondering if there was any way I could override formset.as_table to print it in that form rather than in the way it's presently done. Is this possible, has it already been done somewhere or if not how would you suggest I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always create your own Formset (and possibly Form) subclass that overrides the [`as_table`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.2/django/forms/formsets.py#L342) method to output the forms any way you want.

My suggestion, though, is to consider using [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tags.html#rendering-formsets) and good CSS definitions.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into crispy forms right now, do you have any suggestions on where to look about overriding as_table? I'm looking on the Django API and I can't even find anything about formsets and the other django docs don't provide a whole lot of information about subclassing them.

Comment: In my answer I linked to Django's `Formset.as_table` source code. If the docs are lacking, there isn't a better alternative than the code :-) Make sure to also checkout the forms' [`as_table`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.2/django/forms/forms.py#L213) implementation as well as it's more clear.

Comment: If I use formset_factory to create the formset, am I preventing myself from being able to override as_table?

Answer (score 0):

Override as_table in the class you use for the formset (not the class that uses the formset). Super() the as_table into a variable. Convert that to a string, then repr. Replace "\n" with an empty string. Remove the quote marks at the beginning and end of the repr. Convert that to a string. Call the mark_safe method of the django framework to the resulting string, and return that.